# Is it possible to create an iKEv2 VPN connection using NEPacketTunnelProvider in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension

I am using **NEVPNManager** for VPN connection with ikev2 protocol (personal VPN).
But now I need to use **NEPacketTunnelProvider** for ikev2 (Enterprise VPN).

I found information from an apple developer that you need to develop the protocol yourself:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719182
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664128

This problem seems to be quite complicated.
The search for a solution did not yield any results. Are there any ideas for implementing this solution?

Comment: Sadly Apple's own implementation `NEIKEv2PacketTunnelProvider` is private